# Magento 2: Order Increment Id not working

Tags: magento2, database

In our website, magento order increment id is not working as expected. We are getting difference of 3 between every two orders. Like for example,we have order 000005167 and next order we are getting as 000005170.

And when we checked from DB to know the next autoincrement value,it is showing as follows:

> MariaDB [pkdxthkinb4aa_stg]> SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM
>   information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "pkdxthkinb4aa_stg" AND
>   TABLE_NAME = "sequence_order_1";

+----------------+

| AUTO_INCREMENT |

+----------------+

|           5173 |

+----------------+

While we should get 5171 as the last value in sequence_order_1 table is 5170.

Can you please advice me on how can I fix this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After checking some articles I figured out, there is no other way to make increment by 3 than this:

Magento stores order auto increment id in `sequence_order_1` or `sequence_order_2` table, based on stores. So it uses only **1** increment id by default. Unless someone change `auto_increment_increment` value of database like:

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=3;
```

Try this command and see if your auto increment value is fixed:

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
```

**Note: If you are getting this issue on order increment id and it is occurring due to auto increment value, then it would be occurring on all tables, because it's a global variable**

> Another possible cause

`auto-increment-increment` may be set to `3` in `/etc/my.cnf` file. After update, issue will resolve

Try both scenario one by one

**I hope it will help**

Comment: SET @@auto_increment_increment=1; --> I have tried this but it is showing like 0 rows affected and i have checked the values like SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
but it is still is showing 3 for auto_increment_increment

Comment: Ok Have you checked  the value of `auto-increment-increment` in `my.cnf`?

Comment: NO we are in cloud environment and we don't have access for it to view